# WReq add abritrary cookie to the request

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use the Proxmox VE json API, with wreq I can login and get the json response containing the token to be sent as a cookie with every request. My question now is how do I set a cookie with wreq ? Looks like session handling will automatically handle Set-Cookie sent by the server, but in my case that never happens.

Is there a WReq equivalent to the simple curl -b "Something=Value" in shell ?
Looks like it is possible to call the Cookie constructor by hand but it takes a lot of argument, and I don't really know what I should put in there besides the name and the value.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`getWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.1.0/docs/Network-Wreq.html#v:getWith) which allows you to specify a [CookieJar](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.26.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#t:CookieJar)
with your custom [Cookie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.26.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Client-Internal.html#t:Cookie) values.

```
 {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

 import Network.Wreq.Lens
 import Network.Wreq
 import Control.Lens
 import Network.HTTP.Client
 import Data.Time.Clock

 secs n = n*10^12
 mins n = n*60
 days n = n*1440

 foo = do
   now <- getCurrentTime
   let expires = addUTCTime (days 30) now
       cookie = Cookie "name" "value" expires "example.com" "/" now now True True False False
       jar = createCookieJar [cookie]
       opts = defaults :: Options
       opts' = opts & cookies .~ (Just jar)
   getWith opts' "http://example.com/asd"
```